# ASP - session time out for sub virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a sub virtual directory within a main one and they both have their separate web configs . the main virtual directory has a default sessiontimeout of 20 minutes but I would like my sub virtual directory to have a sessiontimeout of 60 minutes. I have changed the sessiontimeout in the sub's web config but that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS property for that sub directory. In application tab there is a configuration button, click on it and configure session timeout there.